# Can't run `yarn create single-spa` throws `Cannot find module 'restore-cursor'`

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, yarnpkg, nvm

When I try to run `yarn create single-spa` command fails bacause `Cannot find module 'restore-cursor'`

I installed node (with nvm) and yarn with brew

```sh
brew install nvm
brew install yarn
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
nvm alias default node
```

Then when I want to run the commands it fails

```sh
~ ☭ cd Documents
Documents ☭ yarn cache clean
yarn cache v1.22.18
success Cleared cache.
✨  Done in 0.01s.
Documents ☭ yarn create single-spa
yarn create v1.22.18
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "create-single-spa > yeoman-environment@3.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "mem-fs@^1.2.0 || ^2.0.0".
warning "create-single-spa > yeoman-environment@3.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "mem-fs-editor@^8.1.2 || ^9.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-single-spa@4.1.2" with binaries:
      - create-single-spa
[##################################################################################################################] 389/389node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'restore-cursor'
Require stack:
- /Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/cli-cursor/index.js
- /Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/list.js
- /Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js
- /Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/adapter.js
- /Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js
- /Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/create-single-spa/bin/create-single-spa.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/cli-cursor/index.js:2:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/cli-cursor/index.js',
    '/Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/list.js',
    '/Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js',
    '/Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/adapter.js',
    '/Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js',
    '/Users/Enrique/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/create-single-spa/bin/create-single-spa.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /opt/homebrew/bin/create-single-spa
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/Enrique/Documents
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
Documents ☭
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly install `restore-cursor :`

`npm i restore-cursor@last-stable-version-number --save`

Comment: At that point I still dont have any `package.json`, running that [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/create-single-spa/) it's like running `npx create-react-app`